# Bluetooth doesn't show up, Linaro

Tags: ubuntu, arm, bluetooth

```
rfkill list all
```

Shows:

```
0: fxi_c210-bt: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
```

And hcitool dev shows nothing except:

```
Devices:
```

Bluetooth didn't work, but at some start it didn't work anymore.
I already tried to restart and tried to restart the bluetooth service.

Problem is on a linaro-ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the .hcd-file for the bluetooth device in the folder /lib/firmware got corrupted.
I replaced it and it works again. Now hci0 shows up and bluetooth works.